# Spring Framework class resolution with latest neo4j-ogm-core/neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver

Tags: java, gradle, junit, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I am using `Java` and `Gradle` to compile and test [my project](https://github.com/phyloviz/phyloDB).
Running  `gradle -v` outputs the following:

```
gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.4.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-03-31 15:25:29 UTC
Revision:     540473b8118064efcc264694cbcaa4b677f61041

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          21.0.1 (Microsoft 21.0.1+12-LTS)
OS:           Linux 5.15.0-89-generic amd64
```

The code base works under `Java 11`, making use of the following libraries defined in a `build.gradle` file `Gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.0.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java-library'
}

group = 'pt.ist.meic'
version = '1.2.0'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    testImplementation(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '2.2.2.RELEASE') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }

    testImplementation group: 'org.openjdk.jmh', name: 'jmh-generator-annprocess', version: '1.19'

    api group: 'org.openjdk.jmh', name: 'jmh-core', version: '1.19'
    api group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.10.0'
    api group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '1.30.9'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Recently I updated several dependencies to the latest versions and have incurred what seem to be deprecation and compatibility issues.
This required that I also set `Java 17` as target.
To support this version, I updated `Gradle` as well:

```
gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2023-10-04 20:52:13 UTC
Revision:     e9251e572c9bd1d01e503a0dfdf43aedaeecdc3f

Kotlin:       1.9.10
Groovy:       3.0.17
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          21.0.1 (Microsoft 21.0.1+12-LTS)
OS:           Linux 5.15.0-89-generic amd64
```

This is my updated `build.gradle` file.
I am unsure if this is 100% correct as I had to try out different things to get this to compile:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
    id 'java-library'
}

version = '1.2.0'
group = 'pt.ist.meic'
description = "PhyloDB Docker Container App"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-core:4.0.8'
    implementation 'org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver:4.0.8'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api
    implementation group: 'jakarta.servlet', name: 'jakarta.servlet-api', version: '6.0.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '6.1.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '6.1.0'

    api group: 'org.openjdk.jmh', name: 'jmh-core', version: '1.37'
    api group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.16.0'
    api group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '2.2.0'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    testImplementation group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0'
    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '6.1.0'
    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '6.1.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context
    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '6.1.0'


    testImplementation(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '3.1.5') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }


    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter')
    testImplementation('org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-core:4.0.8')
    testImplementation('org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver:4.0.8')
    testImplementation group: 'org.openjdk.jmh', name: 'jmh-generator-annprocess', version: '1.37'

    
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Compilation appears to work fine:

```
gradle bootJar

> Task :compileJava
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 7s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
```

However, when I try to execute the generated JAR file, I get the following error:

```
java -jar build/libs/phylodb-1.2.0.jar

18:51:24.545 [main] INFO  p.i.meic.phylodb.PhylodbApplication - Starting 
PhylodbApplication v1.2.0 using Java 21.0.1 with PID 198252 
(/home/user/phyloDB-official.git/phylodb/build/libs/phylodb-1.2.0.jar started 
by user in /home/user/phyloDB-official.git/phylodb)

18:51:24.547 [main] INFO  p.i.meic.phylodb.PhylodbApplication - 
No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"

18:51:26.485 [main] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Starting service [Tomcat]
18:51:26.486 [main] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardEngine - 
Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.15]

18:51:26.575 [main] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] 
- Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
18:51:26.654 [main] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService 
- Stopping service [Tomcat]
18:51:26.702 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - 
Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'profileService' defined in URL 
[jar:file:/home/user/phyloDB-official.git/phylodb/build/libs/phylodb-1.2.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/pt/ist/meic/phylodb/typing/profile/ProfileService.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: 
Error creating bean with name 'datasetRepository' defined in URL 
[jar:file:/home/user/phyloDB-official.git/phylodb/build/libs/phylodb-1.2.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/pt/ist/meic/phylodb/typing/dataset/DatasetRepository.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: 

Error creating bean with name 'org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session': 
Failed to instantiate [org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session]: Specified class is an interface
```

In particular the following error did not show up with the previous version of `Java` and dependencies:

```
Error creating bean with name 'org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session': 
Failed to instantiate [org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session]: Specified class is an interface

... (I omitted the remaining errors)
```

I am trying to understand what may have caused this problem to emerge.
While it is true that `org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session` is a `Java interface`, this was working in the past, so I believe there may be something wrong with how the Spring Framework is loading classes.
We are using annotations such as `@Repository`, for example [in this file which is one of the triggers of the error](https://github.com/phyloviz/phyloDB/blob/updating/phylodb/src/main/java/pt/ist/meic/phylodb/security/user/UserRepository.java).

The `UserRepository` class in this link has a constructor which receives an instance (implementation) of `org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session` as an argument.
For some reason after updating `Java`, `Gradle` and the dependencies, the Spring Framework is no longer able to create an instance of `org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session`, although I don't know how it did it in the previous versions...

I usually work with `Maven` but this was done in `Gradle` so I aimed to understand how it was designed to work.
I am not sure which one of these packages may be the cause for headaches:

```
implementation 'org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-core:4.0.8'
implementation 'org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver:4.0.8'
implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '6.1.0'
implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '6.1.0'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
```

Any insight would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I spot is that you are jumping from Spring Boot *2.2* directly  on *3.1*. And, even this sounds harsh, the probably least problem is the Java 17 baseline in this case.

Focussing on the Spring Data Neo4j and Neo4j-OGM dependency:
There was a major change in Spring Data Neo4j between version 5 and 6 (happened with Spring Boot 2.4).

This change removed all Neo4j-OGM dependencies from Spring Data Neo4j, even more, SDN was completely rewritten and has its own object mapping now.

Having said this, I am not sure what exactly is causing the exception your are facing. The Spring Boot autoconfiguration for SDN in the newer versions is not aware of any Neo4j-OGM classes and wouldn't touch it.
Maybe this does not matter much, let's solve your problem.

You have two options at hand:
Either upgrade to the new Spring Data Neo4j stack or stick with the "classic" combination of older Spring Data Neo4j and Neo4j-OGM.

The first one will require, based on you current project, some work.
Some features of Neo4j-OGM are not supported in Spring Data Neo4j anymore, like working relationship-centric. Mapping of results is stricter.
If you are willing to go this route, there is a migration guide for the boilerplate: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/reference/appendix/migrating.html
(since it would completely make this thread explode, https://community.neo4j.com/c/drivers-stacks/spring-data-neo4j-ogm/30 would be the best place to ask project-specific questions during migration).

The other option, sticking with the Neo4j-OGM/SDN combination, is supported by https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm-spring This is a fork of the initial Spring Data Neo4j 5 to be compatible with the latest versions of Neo4j-OGM *and* Spring Boot. Please refer to the README for information how to use the custom starter. Also keep in mind that this project is not always up-to-date with the latest releases but maintained on a best-effort base.